# How to redirect back if validate method fails with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 6.
I created a form to insert a meeting and I created a validate method in the controller to check if the data inserted in the db are correct.
Unfortunately when the validate method fails the default redirect back deletes every field that has been compiled by the user.

I tried many times but I am unable to understand how to do in case of failure a redirect back with the previous values filled in by the user.

**Controller:**

```
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'participants' => [ 'required', new CheckParticipant() ], 
            'description' => 'required',
            'room' => [ 'required', new CheckRoom() ],
            'date_meeting' => [ 'required', new CheckDateTime() ],
            'start' => [ 'required', new CheckTime() ],
            'end' => 'required',
        ]);

        $meeting = new Meeting();

        $participants = request('participants');
        $meeting->id_participants = implode(';', $participants);

        $meeting->description = request('description');
        $meeting->id_room = request('room');
        $meeting->date = request('date_meeting');
        $meeting->start_hour = request('start');
        $meeting->end_hour = request('end');

        $meeting->save();

        $message_correct = "The meeting has been correctly inserted!";

        return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', $message_correct);

    }
```

Finally if the user filled in for example the name of a participant to the meeting but the validate method fails I would like that the participant appears already selected in the dropdown menu after the default redirect back.
Is someone able to help me?

Comment: Have you put the code to use the eventual previous data into the form's fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, you can use the [old](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-old) function to retrieve data flashed from the previous request.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `$this->validate` try this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'participants' => [ 'required', new CheckParticipant() ], 
    'description' => 'required',
    'room' => [ 'required', new CheckRoom() ],
    'date_meeting' => [ 'required', new CheckDateTime() ],
    'start' => [ 'required', new CheckTime() ],
    'end' => 'required',
]);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('your/url')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
}
```

Then, in your view you can access the old inputs with `old('yourValue')`.